# sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score zero results

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cohen-kappa

I have predictions and labels arrays as below and I was trying to calculate Kohens Kappa (linear and quadratic) and although almost all the preds are correct, I get 0.0 score of Kappas.

```py
labels = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
preds = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

kappas_linear_cls = cohen_kappa_score(labels, preds)
kappas_quadratic_csl = cohen_kappa_score(labels, preds, weights='quadratic')

linear kappa: 0.0
quadratic kappa: 0.0
```

I am using the built in function `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score`.

How I might solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry for any innconvenience. I thought it is a bug in the metric built-in function itself. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems correct.

The observed agreement ratio (`P0`) is `33/35` (sorry for a possible imprecise count of the total length). Basically, that's the same as accuracy.

The expected agreement (`Pe`) is the sum of products of class probabilities in both vectors: `(2/35 * 0) + (33/35 * 1)` = `33/35`. In other words, if predictions were randomly shuffled, they'd still be correct in 33/35 cases.

Kappa is `(P0 - Pe) / (1 - Pe)` = `(33/35 - 33/35) / (2/35)` = `0`.